# Vue.js: What to display when axios returns error

Tags: vue.js, exception, axios

In a page component, I am using "created()" hook to fetch data using Axios, but when axios returns an error(for example resource not found error), currently it results in an ugly UI as the data that UI requires is not available.

My question is: should there be a global error page or should I need to handle the error for specific situations? Or is there any recommendations regarding Axios error handling with a UI feedback to the user?

Comment: The question is opinion-based. It depends on your choices in UI/UX rather than implementation details. If you feel there should be an alert then do it. If you feel that error message should be shown instead of fetched data then do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle each error and show related alert.